# Multisite Installation is all the same site

Tags: multisite, installation

I have set up my network effectively - but when I go to a subsite dashboard - it is still going to the main site dashboard - I literally changed a whole site and it overwrote my main site.  I was able to restore a backup.  If I go to the direct URL - I do get the new site - hit dashboard or customize and it goes back to the main site dashboard.

I can't figure out how to change the subsites.  Each are their own sites and will be mapped to their own domains, but they are for a single client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like an .htaccess thing.
Have you replaced the contents of .htaccess with the ones provided by WordPress?
Also, [according to the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_4:_Enabling_the_Network), you may need to add `Options FollowSymlinks` at the start of the file.

Comment: I found out the problem.  My client set up a Managed Wordpress hosting with GoDaddy and it doesn't work on that ...you have to switch to Linux or some other hosting and change it to Wordpress.